# Ubuntu 13.10 won't reboot after stalled upgrade

Tags: upgrade, reboot, 13.10

While upgrading to 13.10, my system froze and required a hard reboot. After rebooting, it appears that 13.10 did actually install, but I cannot reboot. System freezes on the purple ubuntu screen. This happens for all reboot methods I could think of including alt+prtScn+b. Shutdown works fine. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

From what I can tell, this is a Grub2 problem. Try using [Boot Repair](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Boot-Repair).

If I helped, please choose my answer, or upvote me.